# What is the complete solution of a $3\times3$ matrix system with eigenvalues of multiplicity 2 and associated eigenvectors?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Given a system

$$x' = 3x +y$$
$$ y'=-x+y $$

Thus, the associated coefficients are

\begin{bmatrix}
3&1\\
-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

If the complete solution for a $2\times2$ matrix is $C_1e^{\lambda t} \vec{u}+C_2e^{\lambda t}(t\vec{v}+\vec{w})$ where $\vec{w}$ solves as $(A-\lambda I)\vec{w}=\vec{v}$

How can we define the complete solution for a $3\times3$ matrix with eigenvalues of multiplicity 2 or three and its associated eigenvectors?

Comment: if the matrix diagonalizes  as $A  = P^{-1}D P$ for diagonal $D$, it is easy to find $e^{At}$ in terms of $e^{Dt}.$   If not,  with extra work one may find $Q^{-1} J Q = A,$   where $J$  is the Jordan form. Same outcome

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a simpler take on this on the question for systems in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and adding on to Will Jagy's comment. We can express this using the Jordan normal form if the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a defective matrix.

Given the first order ODE
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}} = \boldsymbol{Ax} $$
with $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{PJ}\boldsymbol{P}^{-1}$ where $\boldsymbol{J}$ represents the Jordan block and $\boldsymbol{P}$ consists of the (generalized) eigenvectors.

The general solution is given by
$$\boldsymbol{x}=e^{\boldsymbol{A}t}\boldsymbol{x}_0=\boldsymbol{P}e^{\boldsymbol{J}t}\boldsymbol{P}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}_0 = \boldsymbol{P}e^{\boldsymbol{J}}\boldsymbol{c}_0$$
for $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ is a constant vector, and $\boldsymbol{c}_0 = \boldsymbol{P}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}_0$.

To answer your question, let us consider an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assuming the eigenvalues are all the same, ie. $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \lambda$, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, the general solution will be:
$$ \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{P}e^{\boldsymbol{J}t}\boldsymbol{c}_0 $$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
= \boldsymbol{P}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\lambda t} & te^{\lambda t} & \frac{t^2}{2}e^{\lambda t} \\
0 & e^{\lambda t} & te^{\lambda t}\\
0 & 0 & e^{\lambda t}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
for $\boldsymbol{c}_0 = [c_1 \space c_2 \space c_3]^T$.
You can take a look at this link https://math24.net/general-solution-system-differential-equations-jordan-form.html for a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "over-kill" to do this with "matrices", "eigenvalues", and "eigenvectors"!  Given the system of equations x'= 3x+ y and y'= -x+ y, then x''= 3x'+ y'= 3x'- x+ y.  From x'= 3x+ y. y= x'- 3x so x''= 3x'- x+ x'- 3x= 4x'- 4x.

The equation, x''- 4x'+ 4x= 0 is a linear homogeneous second order equation with constant coefficients.  It has associated characteristic equation $r^2- 4r+ 4= (r- 2)^2= 0$ which has r= 2 as double root.  The general solution is $x(t)= Ae^{2t}+ Bte^{2t}$.  $y= x'- 3x= 2Ae^{2t}+ Be^{2t}+ 2Bte^{2t}- 3Ae^{2t}- 3Bte^{2t}= (B- 2A)e^{2t}- Bte^{2t}$.

The general solution to the system is

$x(t)= Ae^{2t}+ Bte^{2t}$

$y(t)= (B- 2A)e^{2t}- Bte^{2t}$